# Catch warnings during registration with simpleITK (python)

Tags: python, c++, itk, image-registration, simpleitk

I'm performing image registration with simpleITK (python) using  `ImageRegistrationMethod.Execute()` approach.
The purpose is to collect some statistics of the image registration process (e.g. find out when it succeeds and when it fails), so I initialize the `ImageRegistrationMethod` instance with different initial transformations, including ones that will not lead to registration success.
Upon execution simpleITK would sometimes throw an exception, which is fine, since I can catch that. But sometimes I get warnings in stderr like this

```
WARNING: In /mnt/emptyplaceholder/projects/elastix/build/ITK-prefix/include/ITK-4.12/itkObjectToObjectMetric.hxx, line 529
Self (0x3a0af70): No valid points were found during metric evaluation. For image metrics, verify that the images overlap appropriately. For instance, you can align the image centers by translation. For point-set metrics, verify that the fixed points, once transformed into the virtual domain space, actually lie within the virtual domain.
```

or this

```
WARNING: In /mnt/emptyplaceholder/projects/elastix/build/ITK-prefix/include/ITK-4.12/itkCorrelationImageToImageMetricv4HelperThreader.hxx, line 85
CorrelationImageToImageMetricv4HelperThreader (0x3a01370): collected only zero points
```

but registration proceeds.

The question is how can I distinguish (from python) instances when registration went completely smoothly from such cases with warnings. A simple and stupid option is to monitor stderr, but maybe there is some ITK functionality to report these occurrences?

Answer (score 1):

It is best to ask this kind of question on ITK's [discourse](https://discourse.itk.org/) forum, which is followed by greater number of ITK experts than `itk` tag on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks a ton! It was wondering where are all the people ever since I started using sitk.